# Is there a way to use a retrieved file name as a variable?

Tags: python

I'm looking to retrieve a list of CSV files, and use these names as variables to open and retrieve their content. Something like this:

```
import csv
import os
files = os.listdir('C:/csvs')
with open(files[0], 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        if line[1]=="**STAFF**":
            pass
        else:
            print(line)
```

If I print `files[0]`, I do get the correct content, but when I try the above code it does not work.

Comment: An error message would be helpful.

Comment: What is your expected vs. actual output?

Comment: You need to specify the full path, e.g. `with open(os.path.join('C:/csvs', files[0]) as csv_file:`

Comment: How do you know it's not working? See how to create a [mcve] and edit the question.

Comment: Your code looks fine, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir(directory_path)` gives filenames which are inside the folder. To actually use the file you need the full path (absolute or relative). This can be easily done by appending each file's name to the directory_path like this:

```py
import os

files = os.listdir(directory_path)
full_file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, files[0])
```

You can also use [glob](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/) to save the trouble of joining the paths.